# JSQMessagesViewController inputToolBar hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-controls, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Recently loaded in JSQMessagesViewController to app but running into a major problem: the input toolbar doesn't load! I've searched all through their github issues, docs and this site.

[Chat view before custom UITextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDRVR.png)

I was able to force the toolbar to appear by loading in my own custom text field but it only appears once my custom field is tapped on.

[Chat view after tapping on custom UITextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFXrh.png)

I'm running this on IOS 10, Swift 3 and Xcode 8. Using current version 8.0 on the develop branch. I have no code in reference to the toolbar outside of the delegate functions.

Im thinking I quick work around could be to just somehow set focus to the input field but wasn't able to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This error only appears on the develop branch. After reverting to the 7.3.4 it works as expected. A nasty bug to say the least, hopefully it gets fixed before an official release.

Comment: Why u r using 3rd party .. better you can write your own .. it is very simple using autolayouts

Comment: Yeah I'll up doing so, if there I can find a fix for this. Open source for Objective-C/Swift is more frustrating than Javascript and that's saying a lot.